# C# SQL Needs to include Profile in WHERE clause

Tags: c#, sql

I'm new to .NET and need to write a SQL statement.  It needs to read something like

```
"SELECT Title, Post, CONVERT(varchar, PostDate, 107) AS DatePosted FROM Posts WHERE RepID = " + Profile("RepID");
```

I need to be able to grab the value of the RepID from the Profile.  When I use the above statement in my code, I get a compiler error that Profile doesn't exist in the current context.  I addded

```
using System.Web.Profile;
```

but I still get the error.  What do I need to do include the RepID in my where clause?  I hope I'm referring the to the Profile correctly.  It's a setting in the security database, I think. I'm new to this and I didn't set up the database, so please be patient with me.

Answer (score 1):

Found what I was looking for.  This is the solution:

```
ProfileCommon profile = (ProfileCommon)HttpContext.Current.Profile;
string sql = "SELECT Title, Post, CONVERT(varchar, PostDate, 107) AS DatePosted FROM Posts WHERE RepID = " + profile.RepID;
```

Hope this helps someone who is trying to figure this out, too.